# Differences with 呢度，喺度，and 喺呢度

Tags: usage, difference, vocabulary, cantonese

Can anyone explain any differences in usage between the three ways of saying 'here' in Cantonese?

I anticipate that in many cases, these will be exchangeable. I'm looking for examples of sentences where one is used and another would be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

- 呢度 = 這裡 = here; this place
- 喺呢度 = 在這裡 = at/ in here; at/ in this place

Example:

**呢度**冇人 (this place has no one) = no one **here**

冇人**喺**呢度 (no one is **at/ in** this place) = no one here

'is' and 'in' can be omitted in 'no one is in here', but 喺 cannot be omitted in Cantonese, 冇人呢度 / 沒人這裡 sounds like two disjoined phrases 'no one, here'

- 喺度 can be short for 喺呢度 (in here) or 喺嗰度(in there)

Example:

你喺度做乜? = what are you doing here/there? (depend on the distance)

Notice:

- 喺 and 在 cannot be omitted in 冇人喺呢度 / 沒人在那裡
- omit 喺 and 在 in 冇人喺嗰度 / 沒人在那裡 (no one is at/ in there = no one there) and writing 冇人嗰度 / 沒人那裡 would change the meaning to 'where there is no one'

More example:

**呢度**唔收信用卡/ **這裡**不收信用卡 = **this place** doesn't take credit cards (呢度 is the subject)

喺呢度，店家唔收信用卡/ 在這裡，店家不收信用卡 = (at/ in)  here, the shop owners don't take credit cards

Answer (score 1):

喺度 means 'speaking' when we answer the phone.

e.g. May I speak to Mr. Tang?

Mr. Tang could reply 喺度.

Comment: 喺度 = 在(這)裡. If I answer the phone with "喺度", it means "(Tang) is here (on the phone with you)". It doesn't mean "Tang is speaking" . "whoever is speaking" is the  English way of answering the phone, Chinese don't say " "Tang 講緊" (Tang is speaking)

Comment: Typical phone call -- 來電者: 「你好，唔該啊 Tang 吖」(hi, Tang please) -- 本人: 「係，我係」(yes, I am Tang). 將 "喺度" 譯為 "speaking" 已經唔係直譯，甚至連意譯都唔係，祇能話係一種"概譯" (rough translation)

Comment: @TangHo There is a very specific usage of "speaking" in English when answering the phone, and it just means "it's me" or "I'm here". It doesn't mean 講緊. Kind of like 喂: I've noticed there are a lot of exceptions and specific idioms when you first pick up the phone.